# Poor performance on ldapsearch

Tags: ldap, openldap, lmdb

I'm migrating an openldap database backend from HDB to MDB. To migrate I repopulate all data on the DB. Write performance is 3x faster which is great but searching has a very low perfomance. In HDB I get responses in a second but with MDB it takes 4 seconds (some timeouts also!). I test several flags for mdb but it only improve write operations.

My database has a million of entries and every entry has many attributes. A single search could return 13K of data (or more). I try to make index of almost all attributes accessed more than one time per query. But the only index that seems to impact the performance is "objectClass".

Some ideas or documents?

Thanks in advance!